# Number of CNN's for processing timeseries using 2D CNN

Tags: time-series, cnn, image-classification

I am processing time-series for classification using 2D CNN model (single channel) where I have converted stationary time series data into 2D image using an "imaging algorithm" known as **Gramian Angular Field** and **Markov Transition Field** as described in this paper [Imaging Time-Series to Improve Classification and Imputation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00327.pdf) using [pyts](https://pyts.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library.

My question is *logically* do I need two different CNN models and then concatenate the output before giving it to the classifier, as I have implemented two different imaging algorithms on the same data?

Or

Can I use a single CNN model with 2 channels, one channel for each kind of imaging algorithm/technique? and then feed the output to the classifier?

In other words, does it makes sense to create different models with different kernels for each imaging technique or can we have all kernels in one model?

Comment: Did you check this code? https://github.com/cauchyturing/Imaging-time-series-to-improve-classification-and-imputation

Comment: This is known as "early" vs "mid" vs "late" fusion.

Comment: @NicolasMartin Yes, checked the code, however, it does not say anything about CNN's or the best architecture to convolve these images in single experiment